# How to deselect the menu section in Navigation-Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

How do I remove the color of the selected section of the image within this function, thank you very much for the help, first code is the onnavigationitemselected, and the second the function which i want to remove the color of the selected

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_mapa)
        {
            // Handle the home action
            MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mapFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_anuncios)
        {
            AnunciosFragment anunciosFragment = new AnunciosFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, anunciosFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_adopciones)
        {
            AdopcionesFragment adopcionesFragment = new AdopcionesFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, adopcionesFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_protectoras)
        {
            ProtectorasFragment protectorasFragment = new ProtectorasFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, protectorasFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_ajustes)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ajustes clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contacto)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contacto Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;

    }
```

**Perfil function:**

```
public void Perfil(View view)
    {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        //per tancar NAV al seleccionar
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
```

**Image which i want to eliminate the selection :**
[image]

Comment: Can u explain me do u want to delete a menu? or remove the color of the selected section?

Comment: remove the color of the selected section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_camera:

                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:

                break;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return false;
    }
```

return false means unchecked state.

or else you can do it like :

```
drawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_camera).setChecked(false);
```

Comment: i want i select a image which has the profile function, removes the color of the selected

Comment: sorry ,I did not get you

Comment: when I call the Perfil function this has to deselect the menu section

Comment: then on the click of profile you can use drawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_camera).setChecked(false);

Comment: Menu menuNav = mNavigationView.getMenu();  MenuItem logoutItem = menuNav.findItem(R.id.menu_logout);

Comment: use your own variable.

Comment: Menu menuNav = navigationView.getMenu();

        menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_mapa).setChecked(false);
        menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_anuncios).setChecked(false);
        menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_adopciones).setChecked(false);
        menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_protectoras).setChecked(false);

Answer (score 0):

you need to se checked false unselect menu item

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(false);
```

`getItem(3)` means you need to pass index of menu item